# Fusion Tables Radius Targeting

Tags: google-fusion-tables

At the moment I have a Fusion Table with 3 columns:

- Column A (text): name of a store
- Column B (location): city of that store
- Column C (number): radius in which the store advertises (so for instance 5km around store location).

Here is a link to the table:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=15YqM0NN0hCc9IfSUfdOiVqS1sFIKehtaYAjg8nU

Now what I would like to do is visualize these advertising radius-es of all these stores on a map. As the radius-es vary for each store (5km for store 1, 10km for store 2, etc.), I have no idea how to start working on this with the API.

I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup this is not possible at all, because your Location-colum is geocoded, it's not possible to access the geocoded LatLng in any manner.

Even when you had the LatLng's it wouldn't be possible to visualize a circle via a FusionTablesLayer, because circles are not supported by KML.

**So the only thing you can do is:**

Request the complete data(may be done via AJAX, JSONP is supported), geocode the City-column an draw a `google.maps.Circle` based on the returned LatLng and the radius stored in the Number-column(of course it would be better when you  had stored LatLng's instead of city-names, because you wouldn't have to geocode the cities each time).